# Echo random number inside Wordpress' get_template_part

Tags: php, wordpress, random, echo

In my Wordpress theme, I have partials folder containing 10 files named with a numerical suffix and I would like to use `get_template_part` to choose 1 random file from of these 10. I thought the simplest way to do this would be by by naming the files with a numerical difference and echoing a random number between 1 and 10—which would be added to the end of the file name listed in `get_template_part`.

Currently I have the following, although I realise you can't run PHP in PHP. Can they be combined with this logic?

`<?php get_template_part('partials/template-',  echo(rand(1,10)) ); ?`>

Files in partial folder named:

```
template-1.php
template-2.php
template-3.php
[...]
template-10.php
```

Can `get_template_part` and the echo number be combined to achieve this?

Comment: You can certainly run PHP in PHP. Remove the hyphen from `template-`. `get_template_part` adds that. `<?php get_template_part('partials/template',  echo(rand(1,10)) ); ?>`

Comment: thanks for the reply. `<?php get_template_part('partials/template',  echo(rand(1,10)) ); ?>` throws an error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ')' in..."

Comment: Then set a variable to the random number. `<?php $number = rand( 1, 10 ); get_template_part('partials/template',  $number ); ?>`

Comment: yup! you got it.

Comment: I'll create an answer, since this is valuable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things:

1. You need to remove the `-` (hyphen) from the `get_template_part()` since WP adds that.
2. You can pass the random number through a variable.

```
<?php
    // Assign the rand number to a variable 
    $number = rand( 1, 10 ); 
    // use the variable in the template part
    get_template_part('partials/template',  $number ); 
?>
```